# How to reload a Safari Extension from the command line?

Tags: applescript, safari-extension

I need to "Reload" a Safari extension from the command line (and also build the package later).

*How can this be done?*

#### Why?

I'd like to build in one step - my code is in CoffeeScript and thus I'm compiling it anyway.

#### What have I tried?

Apart from googling hopelessly I tried using this AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
   tell process "Safari"
       click the button "Reload" of window "Extension Builder"
   end tell
end tell
```

Which errors out with:

> System Events got an error: Can’t get button "Reload" of window "Extension Builder" of process "Safari".

And this variation:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
       tell button "Reload" of window "Extension Builder" to perform action
    end tell
end tell
```

Which doesn't give an error but also doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be that the button isn't "named" as you expect. Check out [UI Browser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/) in order to view an application's interface hierarchy for use with GUI scripting.

The "Reload" button is accessible with:

```
click button "Reload"  of UI element "ReloadUninstall[NAME OF EXTENSION HERE]" \
  of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Extension Builder"
```

Answer (score 2):

Extension Browser's view hierarchy seems to have changed since the accepted answer was written. This script works for me:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
         click button "Reload" of UI element 0 of window "Extension Builder"
    end tell
end tell
```

Note that Safari and the Extension Builder window need to be open for this to work